# How, I do to display the text in Arabic from right to left

Tags: php, html, laravel, arabic, right-to-left

I have a page containing the tag P sometimes, I display a text in English and sometimes in Arabic.
How, I do to display the text in Arabic from right to left and English text from left to right?

```
<p>my text</p>
```

Comment: Either globally `<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">` or `<p dir="rtl">arabic text</p>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

Comment: As I said sometimes contains a text in Arabic and sometimes in English, how do I detect the contents of the P tag before displaying from right to left or left to right?

Answer (score -3):

try this css:

```
.arabic-text {
    text-align: right;
}
```

So, since you're the one putting the text on the website you know what language it is going to be. 
When it is arabic, you add the class to your element. If the text is a sub text (as in a span or a paragraph) within for example a div, put the class on that element.

If you wish to do this programmatically since you may have this text stored in a database, when you create your HTML, you can either add it right there, or you can use javascript to detect a custom data-attribute such as:

```
<p data-language='arabic'>my arabic text</p>
```

and then in javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-language="arabic"]');
```

and then apply your class or the styling directly to the matched elements

Comment: As I said sometimes contains a text in Arabic and sometimes in English, how do I detect the contents of the P tag before displaying from right to left or left to right?

Comment: @nabil I've updated my answer to show you how you can potentially handle it, however remember that without knowing what your project and it's code look like, it's pretty hard to figure out a solution without any code shown.

Comment: I found the solution with <p dir="auto"></p>, thank you